In julia, which is more performant a >= b && c <= b vs !(a<b || c>b)
a >= b && c <= b vs !( a < b || c > b)
Which is more performant in julia?

inspect the assembly, what do you see? measure the execution time, what do you see?

In my case the generated codes are identically. @code_native ((a,b,c)->a >= b && c <= b)(1,2,3) vs @code_native ((a,b,c)->!( a < b || c > b))(1,2,3)

@GKi would you post that as an answer?

In my case the generated codes are identically.
@code_native ((a,b,c)->a >= b && c <= b)(1,2,3)

        .text
        .file   "#1"
        .globl  "julia_#1_61"                   # -- Begin function julia_#1_61
        .p2align        4, 0x90
        .type   "julia_#1_61",@function
"julia_#1_61":                          # @"julia_#1_61"
; ┌ @ REPL[1]:1 within `#1`
# %bb.0:                                # %top
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
; │┌ @ operators.jl:425 within `>=`
; ││┌ @ int.jl:514 within `<=`
        cmp     rsi, rdi
        setle   cl
; │└└
        cmp     rdx, rsi
        setle   al
        and     al, cl
; │┌ @ int.jl:514 within `<=`
        pop     rbp
        ret
.Lfunc_end0:
        .size   "julia_#1_61", .Lfunc_end0-"julia_#1_61"
; └└
                                        # -- End function
        .section        ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits

@code_native ((a,b,c)->!( a < b || c > b))(1,2,3)

        .text
        .file   "#3"
        .globl  "julia_#3_87"                   # -- Begin function julia_#3_87
        .p2align        4, 0x90
        .type   "julia_#3_87",@function
"julia_#3_87":                          # @"julia_#3_87"
; ┌ @ REPL[2]:1 within `#3`
# %bb.0:                                # %top
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
; │┌ @ int.jl:83 within `<`
        cmp     rdi, rsi
        setge   cl
; │└
        cmp     rsi, rdx
        setge   al
        and     al, cl
; │┌ @ bool.jl:35 within `!`
        pop     rbp
        ret
.Lfunc_end0:
        .size   "julia_#3_87", .Lfunc_end0-"julia_#3_87"
; └└
                                        # -- End function
        .section        ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits

@code_native ((a, b, c) -> c <= b <= a)(1, 2, 3)

        .text
        .file   "#1"
        .globl  "julia_#1_61"                   # -- Begin function julia_#1_61
        .p2align        4, 0x90
        .type   "julia_#1_61",@function
"julia_#1_61":                          # @"julia_#1_61"
; ┌ @ REPL[1]:1 within `#1`
# %bb.0:                                # %top
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
; │┌ @ int.jl:514 within `<=`
        cmp     rdx, rsi
        setle   cl
; │└
        cmp     rsi, rdi
        setle   al
        and     al, cl
; │┌ @ int.jl:514 within `<=`
        pop     rbp
        ret
.Lfunc_end0:
        .size   "julia_#1_61", .Lfunc_end0-"julia_#1_61"
; └└
                                        # -- End function
        .section        ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits


@code_native ((a, b, c) -> c <= b <= a)(1, 2, 3) produces similar code and is clearer to me.

Thanks! I added this as another variant not given in the question.

The difference in execution time if it evaluated them verbatim at face value would be too small to measure. Most likely it will transform them into the same executable code. I haven't checked this. This sort of micro optimisation is pointless. You could try doing the measurements yourself and to try prove me wrong
(if you had presented benchmarks you might not have attracted negative votes).
It is very likely that the compiler will turn either of those expressions into whichever canonical form it finds most convenient to evaluate for the datatype that it is dealing with.
FWIW for integers a,b my guess would be that the expression using && might just have the edge at least on x86 series CPUs because of the hardware support of the TEST instruction avoiding a write cycle.
As far as the CPU is concerned all of the comparison flags are set after a compare operation so there is no penalty for > vs <= the conditional branch will be taken or not according to the values of a and b.
PS You should aim for clarity and correctness first. If the algorithm implementation is demonstrably too slow then and only then use profiling to find the hotspots. Too much time is wasted on premature optimisation.
